# How to use the cookie got from Javascript's document.cookie in Ruby mechanize?

Tags: javascript, ruby, cookies, mechanize

I'm automate a login process using Ruby mechanize. Because it's too complex to recreate the exactly process in mechanize, I choose to use existing cookies grabbed from browser `document.cookie`. I want to know how can I use this string in Ruby mechanize. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think Mechanize runs Javascript, you'll have to use something like Selenium for that.

With Selenium, you can run arbitrary scripts. For example:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get("http://some.url")
driver.execute_script("console.log('javascript')")
driver.close
```